# what's the difference between gethostname and getfqdn?

Tags: python, sockets

Just the title, what the difference between them?
In python, `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` and `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` return different results on my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From documentation,

`socket.gethostname` returns a string containing the hostname of the machine where the Python interpreter is currently executing.

`socket.getfqdn` returns a fully qualified domain name if it's available or `gethostname` otherwise.

Fully qualified domain name  is a domain name that specifies its exact location in the tree hierarchy of the DNS. From wikipedia examples:

> For example, given a device with a local hostname myhost and a parent
>   domain name example.com, the fully qualified domain name is
>   myhost.example.com.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the selected reply above is **quite** confusing.

YES `socket.getfqdn` WILL return a full-qualified hostname. But if it's going to be 'localhost.localdomain' you probably actually want `socket.gethostname` instead so that you get something that is somewhat useable.

The difference is that one reads from `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/domainname` while the other reads the kernel nodename. Depending on your distribution, configuration, OS, etc. your mileage **WILL** vary.

What this means is that you generally want to first check `socket.getfqdn`, and verify if it returns 'localhost.localdomain'. if it does, use `socket.gethostname` instead.

Finally, python also has `platform.node` which is basically the same as `socket.gethostname` on python, though this might be a better choice for multiplatform code.

That's quite an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

The hostname is not the fully qualified domain name, hence why they return different results.

`getfqdn()` will return the **fully qualified domain name** while `gethostname()` will return the **hostname**.